# Getting a specific CentOS base image with mkimage-yum.sh

Tags: centos, yum, docker

Docker's `mkimage-yum.sh` does indeed work (awesome little script) but it pulls 6.6 (the latest with updates).  I was wondering if it's possible to specify 6.5.  I believe I can use `yum.conf` but the yum variables don't allow the level of specificity?  For example, you can say `distroverpkg=6Server` but not 6.5 etc.

https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/contrib/mkimage-yum.sh

Maybe I could point it to a 6.5 yum repo mirror from CD media?  Unless someone has a magical `reposync` command.

*Please don't suggest 6.6 or the docker hub images, I have env constraints.*